# How can I convert LinkedHashMap to JSONObject

Tags: java, json, spring, linkedhashmap

ArrayList entries, and this entries is of LinkedHashMap type, I want to convert this into jsonOject for the use, how can I do this?

```
for(Object entry : entries){
            
    JSONObject entryToProcess = (JSONObject) entry;

}
```

Comment: what is the type of JSONObject ?

Comment: Type:
Entries -> LinkedHashMap
I want to traverse on every entries and convert those entry into the jsonObject.

Comment: is JSONObject  is of type org.json.simple.JSONObject ?

Comment: Yes it is the type of org.json.simple.JSONObject

Answer (score 2):

Hi this conversion utility should do.
What happens here is that you call the method `.getKeys()` on the LinkedHashMap object to get all the keys. Then for each key you retrieve the information from the LinkedHashMap and you put it inside the JSONObject

```
    // Your input LinkedHashMap
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    // Providing general values for the test
    linkedHashMap.put("First key", "First value");
    linkedHashMap.put("Second key", "Second value");
    linkedHashMap.put("Third key", "Third value");

    // Initialization of the JSONObject
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    
    // for-each key in the LinkedHashMap get the value and put both of
    // them into the JSON 
    for (String key : linkedHashMap.keySet()) {
        jsonObject.put(key, linkedHashMap.get(key));
    }
```

The part you care about should be the for loop.

Cheers,

Comment: for(Object entry : entries){
                
                
//  JSONObject entryToProcess = (JSONObject) entry;
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                for (String key : entry.keySet()) {
                    jsonObject.put(key, linkedHashMap.get(key));
                }
          }


entry.keySet is not found. error here

Comment: Right, you're calling the method on the wrong object. You should call it on the input LinkedHashMap object to get the key set. I'll edit the answer

Comment: for(Object entry : entries){
                LinkedHashMap<String,?> ll = (LinkedHashMap<String,?>) entry;
                
//  JSONObject entryToProcess = (JSONObject) entry;
                JSONObject entryToProcess = new JSONObject();
                for (String key : ll.keySet()) {
                    entryToProcess.put(key, ll.get(key));
                }
                
                CareContext context = careContexts.get(entryToProcess.get("careContextReference").toString());
  

I am doing this way and the context value I am getting is null, yet it is present i checked

Answer (score 1):

Simple JSONObject constructor would do the trick

```
for(Object entry : entries){
  JSONObject entryToProcess = new JSONObject((LinkedHashMap)entry);
}
```

**Sample:**

```
LinkedHashMap<String,Object> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
linkedHashMap.put("A",1);
linkedHashMap.put("some key","some value");
Map<String, String> someMap = new HashMap<>();
someMap.put("map-key-1","map-value-1");
someMap.put("map-key-2","map-value-2");
linkedHashMap.put("another key",someMap);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(linkedHashMap);
System.out.println(jsonObject.toJSONString());
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "another key": {
    "map-key-1": "map-value-1",
    "map-key-2": "map-value-2"
  },
  "A": 1,
  "some key": "some value"
}
```